# How to highlight in location list error for current line

Tags: neovim, plugin-syntastic

What command could I use to highlight the error in the location list for the line where the cursor is in normal mode? Ie, the inverse operation of selecting a line in the location list and hitting `[enter]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Also answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46754255/3697584)

I just created this for my [:Man viewer](https://github.com/themadsens/thm-dotfiles/blob/master/.vim/autoload/fman.vim). It tracks the current item in the 'locationlist' window when navigating:

```
function! s:visibleLoc()
   return len(filter(getwininfo(), {i,v -> v.loclist}))
endfunc

function! s:followLine()
   let curLine = line(".")
   if (exists("b:lastLine") && b:lastLine == curLine) || 0 == s:visibleLoc()
      return
   endif
   let b:lastLine = line(".")
   let ent = len(filter(getloclist("."), {i,v -> v.lnum <= curLine}))
   if ent < 1 || (exists("b:lastEntry") && b:lastEntry == ent)
      return
   endif
   let b:lastEntry = ent
   let pos = [ 0, curLine, col("."), 0 ]
   exe "ll ".ent
   call setpos(".", pos)
endfunc

au CursorMoved <buffer> call <SID>followLine()
```